# ASP.NET Core 3 MVC : provide a default view if requred view not found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 3 MVC, if you want to load a partial view you do:

```
<partial name= "~/Views/Addresses/existingView.cshtml" model="Model" />
```

Is there any way to tell ASP.NET Core MVC that if that view does not exist load an alternate view instead. For example:

```
<partial name= "~/Views/Addresses/alternateView.cshtml" model="Model" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the C# programming language in razor page.

```
@{

    if (System.IO.File.Exists("Views/Addresses/existingView.cshtml"))
        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Addresses/existingView.cshtml", Model)
    else
        @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Addresses/alternateView.cshtml", Model)

}
```

Screenshots of Test:

[image]

When delete the existingview.cshtml, it will show the alternateView.

[image]